# Removing a certain row in csv file that contains a comma in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have this csv file called **data.csv**:

**Name, Animal and Total** are the header of the file

```
Name    Animal   Total
Ann      Fish      6
Bob      Cat       4
Jim    Dog, Cat    5
```

I want to drop the row if any cells contain a comma, so that the result is this:

```
Name    Animal   Total
Ann      Fish      6
Bob      Cat       4
```

Here's what I tried to do in scala:

```
val data = sc.textFile("file:/home/user/data.csv")
val new_data = data.filter(x => x.contains(","))
```

Unfortunately, this code did not produce the results I wanted. What can I do? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially, if your input data is `csv`, you are going to have always `true` for this condition: `x.contains(",")`.

So, using `.textFile`, every item on `data` will be a line from your file. Assuming that your source file will split every item in your list with a comma (`,`), you can do something like:

```
val new_data = data.filter(x => x.split(",").count() > 3) // where: 3 is the ideal scenario.
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a good way to do this:

```
 def readCsv(filePath: String): List[List[String]] = {

        val bufferedReader = Source.fromFile(filePath)
        bufferedReader.getLines
          .drop(1)
          .map { line =>
            val row = line.split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)", -1).toList
            row
          }
          .toList
      }
```